# SQLite is not storing GUID values properly on MonoDroid and MonoTouch

Tags: c#, sqlite, ado.net, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am using MonoDroid to port the data-layer from my Window Mobile app to Android and iOS. 
My data-layer is working and very well tested on SQL SERVER, SQL CE, and Windows SQLite.

I created class libraries for my projects in my Android Solution and imported all my code. 
I created a new DbEngine Implementation to tweak the queries for SQLite on Mono.

When I insert into tables via text like 'insert into [user] values ('xx', 'hello', null)' it works fine, and I can see the affectedRows > 0. 
However, when I try inserting using a command and parameters, I get incorrect values in the GUID columns please see the screenshot.

```
// Creating the parameter
public override DbParameter CreateParameter(string name, object value)
{
    DbParameter result;
    if (value is byte[])
    {
        var length = (value as Array).Length;
        result = new SqliteParameter(name, DbType.Binary, length) { Value = value};
    }
    else if (value is string && ((string)value).Length > 4000)
    {
        var length = ((string)value).Length;
        result = new SqliteParameter(name, DbType.String, length) { Value = value };
    }
    else if (value is Guid)
    {
        result = new SqliteParameter(name, DbType.Guid) { Value = value }; // up to here, I can see that the GUID has the right value and the SQLiteParameter is created properly. 
    }
    else
    {
        result = new SqliteParameter(name, value);
    }
    return result;
}
```

This is how the rows are inserted when passed as parameters
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a long struggle, it appeared that `GUID` parameters are not supported on `Mono.Data.SQLite`. 
All I needed to fix the issue was in my code when I create the parameter I check if it is `GUID`, I create a parameter of type `string` like the following:

```
result = new SqliteParameter(name, value.ToString());
```

This works fine and stores the values properly and works for querying the database as well. 
It was very frustrating, especially when Xamarin team tells me it is a Unicode issue :(
Hope it helps somebody else.